# pysimplegui update only works in first use

Tags: python, user-interface, python-multithreading, pyserial, pysimplegui

The following program should send data to an STM32 board and update a text element with the received string. Data is correctly sent to the board, which correctly answers back (the program can print the received data to the console every time, for example). Also, the text element is correctly updated with the first received data. However, after the first transmission, even thought the program can continue to print the received data, it hides or deletes the text and does not show it anymore. If another element is used to show a counter that is update on every transmission, this counter is shown without further changes.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import serial
from serial.tools.list_ports import comports

def monitoraSerial():
  valoresExibir = ''
  while True:
    try:
      while interfaceSerial.in_waiting > 0:
        charRecebido = interfaceSerial.read().decode("ascii")
        if charRecebido == '\n':
          window['-VALORES-'].update(valoresExibir)
          valoresExibir = ''
        else:
          valoresExibir += charRecebido
        #window['-VALORES-'].update(interfaceSerial.readline().decode(encoding="ascii")[0:-1])
    except:
      break

window.start_thread(monitoraSerial, '-ENCERRASERIAL-')

while True:
  event, values = window.read()
  if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
    break
```

The received data is formated as `"p: %d, i: %d, d: %d, f: %d\n"` .

What should I change, please?

I've tried:

- forcing `visible` attribute to `True`;
- calling `refresh` and `finalize`;
- `readline` method;

Expected the `'-VALORES-'` element to update in every transmission.

`'-VALORES-'` is update only in the first transmission and disappears from the second on.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding threads made it work (maybe this new update logic would work in the thread, but I'd rather don't use one):

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import serial
from serial.tools.list_ports import comports

valoresExibir = ''
deveAtualizar = False

while True:
  event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
  if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
    break
  
  window.refresh()

  while interfaceSerial.in_waiting > 0:
    charRecebido = interfaceSerial.read().decode("ascii")
    if charRecebido == '\n':
      deveAtualizar = True
    else:
      valoresExibir += charRecebido

  if deveAtualizar:
    deveAtualizar = False
    window['-VALORES-'].update(valoresExibir)
    valoresExibir = ''

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can receive data by thread.

Demo Code

```py
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def rfi_reader(window):

    # Should call method `window.write_event_value` not in main thread for all GUI updates

    global running                          # flag to stop thread

    while running:
        sleep(2)    # simulate action
        message = datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S ") + "New Message"
        window.write_event_value('RFI Message', message)

    window.write_event_value('End', None)   # Event for thread end


font = ('Courier New', 16)
sg.theme('DarkBlue4')
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Start'), sg.Button('Exit')],
    [sg.StatusBar('', auto_size_text=False, key='Message')],
]
window = sg.Window('GPIO', layout, enable_close_attempted_event=True)

running = False
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT, 'Exit'):
        if running:
            running = False
        else:
            break
    elif event == 'End':                        # wait thread end
        break
    elif event == 'Start' and not running:      # Start thread
        running = True
        threading.Thread(target=rfi_reader, args=(window, ), daemon=True).start()
    elif event == 'RFI Message':                # Update message from thread
        message = values[event]
        window['Message'].update(message)

window.close()
```